# What is the simplest way to send message from local service to activity

Tags: android

I have a service which is listening to the phone.  When the phone goes IDLE, I want to send a message to my Activity.  It looks like I have two options to accomplish this.  BroadcastReceiver and binding to the Service.  BroadcastReceiver looked like an easier mechanism, so I tried the following test.

In my Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("MyAction");
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Yay.......");
            abortBroadcast();
        }
    }, filter);
}
```

In my Service which is listening for events, when I detect my desired event:

```
    Intent localIntent = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setAction("MyAction");
    _context.sendOrderedBroadcast(localIntent, null);
```

In my test, the onReceive() method is never called after I have watched the broadcast being sent with the debugger.  What am I missing?  Also, is a BroadcastReceiver the simplest way for a local service to communicate with an Activity?

Comment: does your manifest have the appropriate <intent-filter>?

Answer (score 4):

I think I had a few problems in my initial test case.
1. When I created my Intent in my service, it should take the "action" as the argument.
2. I believe that I needed to add the intent filter to my manifest.

My working example now is:

Activity:

```
        startService(intent);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PhoneListeningService.PHONE_IDLE);
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Yay.......");
            }
        }, filter);
```

Manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ncc.PhoneListeningService.action.PHONE_IDLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Service:

Declare public constant for the named "action" and broadcast an intent.

```
public static final String PHONE_IDLE = "com.ncc.PhoneListeningService.action.PHONE_IDLE";
```

... my listener detects phone idle:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(PHONE_IDLE);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you for short and concise example! @aaaaaaa: yes, it works.

Comment: ...except that you need to unregisterReceiver() when activity stops... but that's a minor fix.